# javascript /jquery for loop doesn't work with extremely complicated expression

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this javascript:

```
<script>
$("#P1").on("blur", function(){$("#Y1").val(getClass(this));});
$("#P2").on("blur", function(){$("#Y2").val(getClass(this));});
$("#P3").on("blur", function(){$("#Y3").val(getClass(this));});
$("#P4").on("blur", function(){$("#Y4").val(getClass(this));});
<script>
```

It's written in jquery. I want to tokenize it in a for loop. I have tried several iterations of syntax, but I can't get one that works with the complex expression.

```
<script>
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
$("#P" +i).on("blur", function(){$("#Y" +i).val(getClass(this));});
}
</script>
```

How come this doesn't work?

Comment: Well, `"#Y1" +i` should probably be `"#Y" +i` ... is it a typo in the question or the real code? `"Y1" +i` is going to be "Y10", "Y11" ... "Y14"

Comment: typo.. I fixed it. This for loop replaced 48 statements and the solution is a godsend.

Comment: Good fix, I think this is a common pattern so upvoted the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the `for` loop, `i` has a value of 5, so every time the `blur` handler is called, the interpreter will see `i` with a value of 5 - and #Y5 doesn't exist if you only have #Y1-4.

Use `let` instead, which has block scope rather than function scope, so that every iteration has a separate binding for `i`:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  $("#P" + i).on("blur", function(){
    $("#Y" + i).val(getClass(this));
  });
}
```

Always use `let` (or `const` if you can) when you're using `for` loops, especially if there's anything asynchronous involved. (Actually, you should be using `let` or `const` everywhere you can regardless, but it's especially important with `for` to avoid bugs)

Comment: That sounds like sage advice. I'll take it to heart.